# Remote Video Share using teamviewer

Tags: video, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I'm using teamviewer 8. I've a remote computer to monitor and teamviewer is doing a excellent job since 2012. But the only problem i face, if i need to see the video (cam) of the remote PC somebody has to share it. Unless, there's no way to see. one alternative I've found that's from the video settings(on remote PC) but the quality is not that quality. Is there any way to share without requiring someone else to share? Thanks.

Comment: I believe teamviewer 9 supports this.

Comment: Nope, same( I tried this when they just released Version 9). Actually Accessing remote computer's Video is intentionally disabled by Teamviewer, maybe for the privacy issues. I upgrades mine to Teamviewer 9, and still there was no solution, besides there is a problem in Teamviewer 9 that you can't exit the Teamviewer in a normal way, (exit option is disabled). So, later I downgraded to Teamviewer 8.

Comment: Finally I find The solution just now. Only it is available in teamViewer Corporate. Thanks everyone. I had to purchase both premium and corporate version to find this out :(

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround, tested with TeamViewer 10:

1. Open the TeamViewer video-panel on the remote computer. The video-area will be greyed out.
2. Use the Windows Snipping Tool to see through the greyed out video-area and to find the exact location of the "enable video" button.
3. Hide the TeamViewer panel on the remote computer.
4. Enable the TeamViewer option "Show remote cursor".
5. Use the free and portable Software TinyTask to record a macro that performs a mouse click exactly at the position where the "enable video" button was located before.
6. Compile the macro to save it as an .exe file.
7. Open TeamViewer video panel on the remote computer again.
8. Run your .exe macro and watch the remote cursor magically confirming the video connection for you.

Comment: Well, thanks. But I have found the solution with teamViewer Corporate , problem solved and things are running well so far.